# Unable to create a new ASP.NET Core project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Visual Studio 2019.

I am trying to create ASP.NET Core Web Application with Razor page.

After selecting the 'ASP.NET Core Web Application' template, providing name for the application and then selecting 'Web Application' from the list as shown below:

[selecting Web Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LCwG.png)

After I click Create, the following 'Creating Project ' comes up for around 10 minutes before Visual Studio Not Responding message comes and I have to close the application.
[Creating Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbaK1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run a Repair on on Visual Studio 2019 installation. That will take an hour or so and than retry. If it doesn't work than uninstall and than re-install again.

Comment: I am glad it worked for you ! Mark it as the answer if it worked for you, so that other people may benefit from it !